# Validation with Request.Form["variable"] values

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, validation

I'm having trouble making validation work in my form. The form consists of several text fields that are required for the form to post. My value attribute on each input field has this structure:

```
value="@(Request.Form["navn"] != null ? Request.Form["navn"].ToString() : "")"
```

I have added the `required` attribute to the fields which need validation, but the form is still being submitted, even when the required fields are empty.

All input fields are enclosed in a single form field, and the submit button has the type "submit". Here is the beginning of my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="?action=send" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">Forespørgsel på booking: <strong>@contentName</strong></legend>

        <!-- Navn input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Navn *</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="navn" name="navn" type="text" placeholder="Indtast venligst dit navn..." class="form-control" value="@(Request.Form["navn"] != null ? Request.Form["navn"].ToString() : "")" required>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using  the `IsPost` property with an If statement, to check whether the form was submitted and doing my data layer code there. What can I do to make validation work with my form?

Comment: search for "unobtrusive javascript validation"

Comment: Thanks, I managed to have the form not submit when my required values were left empty. However it is not showing any message indicating that the field is required, even though I have the data-val-required attribute set to a message.

Comment: within the form tag you need to have following 'div' tag so that errors are displayed in that                                                          <div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul class="errorlist"><li></li></ul></div>

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to display the messages below each input element!